# Keep variables when switching namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm using the following snipped to create a namespace, inject the given list of symbols and their values in the current namespace into the new namespace and switch to the new namespace:

```
(defn in-ns-with-vars
  "Switch to a new namespace (creating it if necessary) and 
   inject the given symbols into the new namespace
   with the values they resolve to in the current namespace."
  [new-ns-symbol & symbols-to-inject]
  (let [n (create-ns new-ns-symbol)
    current-value-of (fn [v] @(ns-resolve (the-ns *ns*) v))]
    (do
      (doseq [v symbols-to-inject]
        (intern new-ns-symbol v (current-value-of v)))
      (in-ns new-ns-symbol)
      (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core))))
```

Is there an existing mechanism to achieve this? Due to usage in a scripting context the current (initial) namespace is statically unknown, so I cannot refer to it statically.

Comment: Why not alias or refer `*ns*` in the newly created namespace?

Comment: This works; if you turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new var pointing at the old var's value, you can use `alias` or `refer` with the captured symbol of the runtime `*ns*` to make the bindings visible in the newly created namespace.

```
user=> ((juxt identity type) (.name *ns*))
[user clojure.lang.Symbol]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `import-vars` function from the [potemkin](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin) library can do this for you (after using `*ns*` to reference your original namespace).